# PHP 7 Unicode-support and platform-independence

Tags: php, php-7

It's announced that [PHP 7 supports "consistent 64-bit"](http://php.net/archive/2015.php#id2015-06-25-1). What does this mean?

Does PHP 7 support Unicode similar to what was [planned for PHP 6](http://www.derickrethans.nl/talks/php6-unicode.pdf) (`unicode.semantics` directive, etc.)? If not, when will it support Unicode natively?

Comment: Why the repost? Why are you still mixing up the two topics? Long integers and Unicode have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 8):

### Consistent 64-bit support

I think this relates to [RFC: 64 bit platform improvements for string length and integer in zval](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/size_t_and_int64_next).

It looks like the visible part of the iceberg is, as @cybersoft has mentioned already, that PHP 7 x64 on Windows now has 64-bit integers, whereas PHP 5.6 x64 still had 32-bit integers on this platform.

There is a RFC for a [64-bit integer type](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/64bit-integer-type), but it's still work-in-progress since 2010, so it looks like we're still not getting a 64-bit integer on 32-bit platforms here.

### Unicode support

AFAIK, there is no such thing as a Unicode implementation similar to what was planned for PHP 6. PHP will still deal with a binary `string` type for the foreseeable future, and the [RFC for UString](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/ustring), which proposes to add a new type for Unicode strings, is still under discussion, so will not make it into PHP 7.0.

PHP however, still works quite well with UTF-8, as long as you use [mb_*()](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) functions instead of the basic string functions.

Note that PHP 7 also introduces a [Unicode Codepoint Escape Syntax](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/unicode_escape) that helps dealing with UTF-8 strings.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, this means that the 64-bit version of PHP now has 64-bit integers. Previously, there were only 32-bit integers on x64 Windows.