# What does actually mean by "Native Unicode Support" in PHP and why PHP does not support "Native Unicode Support" even in PHP 7 releases?

Tags: php, unicode, byte, native, php-7

**P.S. :** I'm using **PHP 7.2.2** on my machine that runs on **Windows 10 Home Single Language** edition. I'm using PHP from the installed **XAMPP v3.2.2**

Consider all my doubts as regarding to **PHP 7** only.

Please have a look at the following text from the [**Strings** page of **PHP Manual**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string) :

> A string is series of characters, where a character is the same as a
>   byte. This means that PHP only supports a 256-character set, and hence
>   does not offer native Unicode support.

The above text has raised so many questions in my mind as below :

1. What does actually mean by **"256-character set"** in the context of PHP here? Which 256 characters are involved in this so called **256-character set**? What is the official name of this **"256-character set"** in PHP context?
2. What does actually mean by **"Native Unicode Support"**?
3. I heard that abandoned PHP 6 release was about to incorporate **"Native Unicode Support"** but somehow it never got released and finally abandoned. So, I expected PHP 7 will incorporate **"Native Unicode Support"** but the manual is saying it still doesn't supported as of PHP 7? Why so?
4. How PHP overcame this drawback in PHP 7 releases?
5. Can the website be created in PHP which supports multiple languages, especially Indian Languages as PHP is not having **"Native Unicode Support"**?

Comment: Answer to your first question.... [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

Comment: 2. you need fancy functions to work with unicode. http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php

Comment: Most PHP core/string functions assume single-byte encoded ASCII/Latin-1 text. UTF-8 encoded strings typically do not pose a problem, but `strlen`/`substr` et al only deal on a byte-by-byte basis still. So what this means is: apart from specific regex/multibyte functions, PHP does not interpret character-encoding in strings per default. There's no `unicode`-type/default for strings such as in e.g. Python3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What factors make PHP Unicode-incompatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571694/what-factors-make-php-unicode-incompatible) and/or [PHP 7 Unicode-support and platform-independence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31066789/php-7-unicode-support-and-platform-independence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It means first 256 (out of 1 114 112 possible characters; 17 x 65 536) characters of [Unicode characters set](https://unicode-table.com/en/).
2. Native letters, like ą, č, etc.
3. Native letters are placed at the end of Unicode set after 256 character position, so that's why PHP does not support it.